# ImportError: No module named mongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I wrote a simple script that save a JSON in mongo database, my problem is that when I run this script I get a message `ImportError: No module named mongo`, why I'm getting this error:

```
import mongo
    json = {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A green door",
        "price": 12.50,
        "tags": ["home", "green"]
    }
    mongo.db.test.update(
                            {'_id': '123456789'},
                            {'$set': final_result}
                    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the `pymongo` module, not `mongo`.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

Or just

```
import pymongo
```

See some examples in the [documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html).

Comment: I get the a mistake : NameError: name 'mongo' is not defined

Comment: @EgzontinaK you need to change `mongo` to `pymongo` in Line 8 of your code. Once you import a module, you need to refer to it by its name.

Comment: @MattDMo now i'm getting this:  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'db'

Comment: @EgzontinaK Please read the pymongo documentation and follow the instructions. You need to initialize a db instance using `MongoClient` prior to accessing the db.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pymongo
```

or

```
easy_install pymongo
```

For more information you can look at [PyMongo installation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html)

Comment: I did that, it's already installed . If i do it once i get this message: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
And still i get the same error message